# What does it mean for two lines to be equal?

Tags: geometry

Since two points determine a unique line, does it mean that if both lines have those two points they are equal or must all points be the same?

Comment: Both criterions describe when lines are equal. $(1)$ They contain the same points $(2)$ They contain two distinct(!) fixed points. You can also say : If two lines contain two distinct points $A$ and $B$, then they contain already the same points and are therefore equal.

Comment: Terminology alert: in geometry, we do not use the term *equal*. In the context of your question, *identical* is a better term. When two objects (line segments, for example, or triangles) are the same size and shape, we say they are *congruent*.

Comment: Most contemporary geometry texts will talk of two line *segments* being equal *length* (which has nothing to do with the points contained) whereas some older texts might refer to line segments as "lines" and "equal" with the meaning equal length being imply.  Other texts might talk of points, lines, etc.being equal meaning they are identical and the same object (so no "both"; they are simply to references to one thing).  Note: no two different lines ever have two or more points in common. So "$l_1$ and $l_2$ have two points in common so $l_1=l_2$" means that "they" are the same single line.

Comment: IMO "equal" although troublesome, is not completely bad or unwarranted.  We talk of points $p $ and $q $ being equal so why not lines or triangles or any other object?  We must be careful that when we note "two" things are equal that "they" are actually only one single item that is being referred to twice. It's easy for me to imagine a case where in proving we determine what we specified as two lines will contain two points in common and thus we would conclude the two lines are "equal" and thus the same line.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether equal is (at least in the Euclidean sense) the correct terminology. Identical is more fitting.

---

Two lines on the Euclidean space can be either identical, parallel (have no common point) or intersect on a single (common) point.

So, we assume that we have two lines $l_1,l_2$ such that they have two points $A, B$ with $A\neq B$, and $A, B \in l_1$ and $A, B \in l_2$.

Let's suppose that $l_1$ and $l_2$ are parallel. Since they share at least one common point, say $A$, we get a contradiction. Thus they cannot be parallel.

Let's suppose now that $l_1$ and $l_2$ are intersecting. If $l_1, l_2$ intersect, they must do so at a single (common) point, but since $l_1$ and $l_2$ have more than one common points they cannot intersect.

It follows that $l_1$ and $l_2$  are identical.

---

As a sidenote, remember that a line is *defined* by two points but *contains* infinitely many points.

Comment: @Math4Life My pleasure!